# ElasticSearch 6.4: no master re-election until node restart

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm experimenting with a cluster of two master-eligible nodes (**node30**, **node207**) and I noticed that master re-election process doesn't start unless I restart the non-master node.

Below is my node *elasticsearch.yml* (the second node - **node207** - has a similar one, with a different node.name only):

```
    network.host: 0.0.0.0
    cluster.name: mycluster
    node.name: node30
    discovery.zen.no_master_block: all
    discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["node30", "node207"]
```

Here's my scenario:

1. Start both nodes and **node30** becomes a master node. Cluster health shows two nodes in a cluster.
2. Disable TCP ports 9200/9300 on **node207**. There are networking errors in **node207** logs. No master is visible.

   According to documentation - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/modules-discovery-zen.html - after 3 retries (ping_retries) **node207** should elect itself as the new master (discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes is 1 by default). This never happens.
3. Restart **node207**. After several failed attempts to ping the old master (**node30**), it will elect itself as a master.

Without restarting, master re-election is not happening.

Is it expected behavior?

Answer (score 1):

> discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes is 1 by default

This is a misconfiguration. You must set `discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes` to `2` since you have two master-eligible nodes.